# What can conclude from this two examples

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so i stumbled across two task that says, is the given equation unique

1. $y' = \sqrt{y} + 1, y(1) = 0$

So this equation is continuous, but it does not satisfy Picard theorem, because $dF/dy = 1/2\sqrt{y}$ so we do not know is the equation unique, but I can divide the initial equation by $\sqrt{y} + 1$ and multiply with $dx$ then I should have $$\frac{dy}{\sqrt{y} +1} = dx,$$ and after Integrating i get $$\sqrt{y} +1 -\ln\left(\sqrt{y} +1\right) = x/2 + c.$$

Then after i put in $(1,0)$ in equation I should get $c = 1/2$. Does this mean that i Have unique equation because i find c and i have only one equation?

2. $y' = 3\sqrt[3]{y^2} ,y(1) = 0$

Same thing it does not satisfy Picard theorem but i can find equation $y = (x + c)^3$ and then after putting $(1,0)$ in equation I got $c = -1$, so my equation is $y =(x-1)^3$.
Does this mean that is my unique equation or i do not have unique equation?

Comment: This is pretty unreadable. Please us MathJax to make your equations readable.

Comment: Clearly $y=0$ solves the second IVP.